# My computer broke, monitor doesn't light up and windows doesn't load all the way unless in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, hardware-failure

I left my pc running and fell asleep to that. I woke up a few hours later, heard that it still works, and somehow half asleep turned it off by holding "off" for a few seconds.

When I woke up, monitor isn't working. I connected my notebook to an external monitor, it sort of worked, but windows didn't load all the way in. I tried safe mode, it works, I backuped the most important things. In the safe mode I disabled "reload on error" in the "sysdm.cpl", now it just displays black screen instead of reloading endlessly.

I suspect that it's somehow related with overheat, or hdd failure. Or maybe some autostart program. I suspect that my pc reloaded due to overheat, and was restarting over and over, which made him even more overheated. Or maybe I wasn't gentle enough when opening my laptop, and monitor got damaged.

What can I do from now? How can I read logs? I tried "event viewer" or how it is, it doesn't fit on my external monitor.

I can try "recovery live usb", but which one?

BSOD showed me 0x166 and atikmpag.sys. And my ventilator works much much more than it should. Must be an overheat then, I wonder how much was fried.

How can I set my pc so that it STOPS RELOADING on errors, and just shuts off? It fuken fried up my laptop.

Comment: If it works in safe mode, it could just be corruption.  As a first step, boot in safe mode and run `chkdsk /r` and `sfc /scannow` (run from elevated command line).

Comment: The very suspicious thing is that the screen just doesn't work anymore. At all. I have to use the external one.

Comment: There could be more than one problem, so just address them one at a time, starting with easy, free potential fixes that don't have a lot of side effects.  Use an external monitor and try the cleanup in my earlier comment.  Report the results and we can go from there.  If there's an overheating issue, leave it off for several hours to cool down.  Make sure there's no internal dust and make sure you're using it on a hard surface so the vents aren't blocked.

Comment: Ok, I have run both. First `chkdsk` did something, but I fell asleep before it reported the result. Second `sfc` told me that it found something, but it can't fix it, and just told me the location of the log file.

Comment: Other news, I disabled my video driver in the device manager, now I can start my computer without safe mode. Hooray. My monitor is still broken though.

Comment: It's either my on board gpu chip was fried, or connection to monitor lost, or monitor itself was broken. How can I figure out what exactly happened.

Comment: It sounds like there are still some OS issues that sfc couldn't fix, so the next step would be restoring the OS.  What exactly is your question about which recovery USB to use?  When you boot, is there a recovery option (often a small partition stored on the hard disk), or were you instructed to create a backup/restore flash drive or DVD set when the system was new?  Also, disconnect the external monitor and start at the BIOS screen.  Try using a flashlight on the screen to see if there is any content faintly visible when you illuminate it.  If so, it could mean that just the backlight is out.

Comment: BTW, one more thing to try before restoring Windows: atikmpag.sys is part of the video driver, so it could be that just that is corrupt.  Try replacing that file or use the Device Manager to load the latest video driver.  You can get the complete driver at the laptop manufacturer's web site (preferred), or the AMD site (last resort).

Comment: Hm, no, internet is full of reports of 0x166 atikmpag.sys BSOD appearing when videocard overheats. Driver is fine, but videocard is ded, most likely. And monitor too, for some reason.

Comment: I unscrewed my laptop, left connection to the monitor just broke. Looks like I broke it while trying to turn laptop off while half asleep. Let's see if it's possible to fix yet. I had it coming.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned which Windows version you're running but I'm assuming Windows 10 here. Your computer is booting in safe mode which is already a good sign as it means that not everything is broken. It could mean that a driver got corrupted but it could also mean that part of the hardware is malfunctioning and booting in safe mode just means not using that part of the hardware or not using it as intense.

I suggest you attempt to repair your Windows installation using the media installation tool. On another PC, go to [the Microsoft download website](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=616447) and create a USB drive or DVD for your laptop.

Then, boot the laptop from the USB drive/DVD, select the language and architecture (32-bit or 64-bit) and select "Repair your computer". You can then first try to go back to a previous system restore point which will allow you to keep your applications and date. If that fails, please try the "Reset this PC" option. If that also fails, you can use the USB drive/DVD you created to reinstall Windows 10.

For Windows 7 the process is quite similar. Insert your Windows 7 DVD and boot from it. Enter the language preferences and select 'Repair your computer' and then try the 'Startup repair' functionality. If that fails then you should reinstall Windows.

If it's a notebook or desktop with an OEM Windows version it's likely that you didn't get a Windows DVD. Please refer to your manual to see how you can access the recovery options. This is usually done by pressing a specific key during boot.

Comment: It's windows 7 actually, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: I'm sure it's a hardware problem by now. Either the gpu chip or the monitor. If I'm lucky, it's just the connectors.

Answer (score -1):

mmh at this point if you have everything backed up the best is to reinstall windows, start all over

pros : 
no problem on your winbows 'cause it's new

cons : 
the screen might still not work

you lose your windows licence

hope this help

Comment: Reinstalling Windows is not guaranteed to fix this problem, especially if it is a problem to do with the hardware. Even so, you should provide actual instructions on how to reinstall Windows rather than assume that the user knows how to. In fact this answer would work better as a comment in its current state; keep in mind that Stack Exchange and its sites are not forums.